# How to remove caption field from ckeditors table dialog box?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to remove caption field from ckeditors table dialog box which i dont want users to use.DOes anyone know how to remove such fields ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is described here (1. question) http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows-section-1

Comment: Was solving with same approach but i was not able to get the id of that field.Thanks a lot...